# How to login to individual ESXi systems via ssh given vSphere admin access?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

Given full admin access to vSphere, how can I translate that access to the ability to login via SSH to invididual ESXi systems to do some low level maintenance? Can I log in with the vSphere credentials (they are AD integrated) to a managed ESXi system for which I don't have any local credentials?

Comment: What type of low-level maintenance are you suggesting?

Comment: Adding an esx vib, force syncing time, pruning logs

Comment: Is there a reason you can't obtain host credentials?

Comment: Shared passwords aren't ideal.

Comment: How can we help with that?

Comment: @ewwhite it would generally seem sensible as a product feature that if you are an admin on vSphere you can also manage the ESXi hosts. vSphere access can use AD, same as ESXi but these aren't cascaded down as far as I understand - you'd have to separately add ESXi and vSphere to AD. Seems strange.

Comment: It's not an odd situation. This is privilege separation. If you don't have free and clear access to the ESXi hosts, then you probably shouldn't be the one installing host-level VIBs or touching logs. Network time can be accomplished via the vSphere GUI. You should never have to prune host-level logs.

Comment: @ewwhite - I agree it’s odd but then this isn’t a case of “stupid admin doing what smart admins don’t let him”. And no - you can’t force time be synced from vSphere if it’s drifted to the second and host logs need pruning if some vibs are buggy and won’t autorotate (hp for example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSH access is separate from the vSphere vCenter, and SSH access should only be enabled for odd maintenance or troubleshooting tasks, and then promptly disabled again thereafter. You'll need the root account details for each and every host to access the SSH shell.

Comment: Thanks - I've accepted this as answer as it aligns with my research on the topic. Whether SSH should or shouldn't remain enabled is a matter of some debate and not relevant to the question hwover

Comment: Official VMware guidelines states so, and it's the default behaviour of vCenter/vSphere. But yes, I personally can't quite understand it either.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely ask the parties responsible for the ESXi hosts for the root credentials.

Your vSphere credentials don't directly translate into host-level credentials.
You *may* have the ability to add local users to the hosts.

What type of low-level maintenance are you trying to perform? In normal use cases, root or SSH access to the ESXi hosts is not needed.